# Minted Package, inline background color

Tags: minted

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[semibold]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newmintinline{python}{python3, fontsize=\scriptsize, bgcolor=bg}

Of these, \pythoninline{generators} is one of the biggest culprits. I'm guessing this is the case for most novice Python programmers.

\end{document}
```

produces[image]

Is it possible to make the bottom part of the painted area shorter?

Comment: `minted` uses a minipage with `\colorbox` to display coloured stuff with background. This means, that `\fboxsep=0.1pt` should do the trick`, but this will change all spaces (top, bottom, left, right) of the displayed coloured box

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: There is certainly a `tcolorbox` alternative isn't it?

Comment: @HarishKumar: Yes, I think so: A `\DeclareTColorBox` stuff which does the minted stuff internally?

Comment: @Christian. Thanks. `\fboxsep=1.5pt` did it for me.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I think very simple: `extrude bottom by` key.

Comment: @HarishKumar: Too easy :-P

Comment: @blackened: I added a more convenient solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the manual of `minted`, a `minipage` and an underlying `\colorbox` is used if the `bgcolor=...` option is applied.

Since `\colorbox` uses the `\fboxsep` length as separation between text and box 'frame', it's sufficient to change `\fboxsep`.

Applying a patch to `\minted@inputpyg@inline` this will succeed:

```
\xpatchcmd{\minted@inputpyg@inline}{%
  \colorbox%
}{%
  \fboxsep\mintedfboxsep%
  \colorbox%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\makeatother
```

Since this all happens in a group (see the detailed definition in `minted.sty`, the outer `\fboxsep` value isn't changed.

However: `\fboxsep` is a common length for all four separations of a `\fbox` or `\colorbox` box, i.e. the top, bottom, left and right separations are changed **all** if `\fboxsep` is modified!

This is a quick patch to change the underlying `\fboxsep` length.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[semibold]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}


\newlength{\mintedfboxsep}
\setlength{\mintedfboxsep}{1.5pt}

\newmintinline{python}{python3, fontsize=\scriptsize, framesep=0.1pt,bgcolor=bg}

\xpatchcmd{\minted@inputpyg@inline}{%
  \colorbox%
}{%
  \fboxsep\mintedfboxsep%
  \colorbox%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}



Of these, \pythoninline{generators} is one of the biggest culprits. I'm guessing this is the case for most novice Python programmers.

\end{document}
```

**Edit**

What I've stated above about `\fboxsep` is true here, but I've changed the internal definition of `\colorbox` for the minted inline code only, introducing four lenghts:

`\fboxrsep`, `\fboxlsep`, `\fboxtsep` and `\fboxbsep`, each responsible for `right`, `left`, `top` and `bottom` separation.

Use one of the various `\setlength{...}{}` statements to change at will.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in, margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[semibold]{sourcecodepro}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.9, 0.9, 0.9}


\newlength{\mintedfboxsep}
\setlength{\mintedfboxsep}{0.2pt}

\newmintinline{python}{python3, fontsize=\scriptsize, framesep=0.1pt,bgcolor=bg}

\makeatletter
\newlength{\fboxrsep}
\setlength{\fboxrsep}{\fboxsep}

\newlength{\fboxlsep}
\setlength{\fboxlsep}{\fboxsep}

\newlength{\fboxtsep}
\setlength{\fboxtsep}{\fboxsep}

\newlength{\fboxbsep}
\setlength{\fboxbsep}{\mintedfboxsep}

\xpatchcmd{\minted@inputpyg@inline}{%
  \colorbox%
}{%
  \long\def\color@b@x##1##2##3%
  {\leavevmode
    \setbox\z@\hbox{\kern\fboxlsep{\set@color##3}\kern\fboxrsep}%
    \dimen@\ht\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxtsep\ht\z@\dimen@
    \dimen@\dp\z@\advance\dimen@\fboxbsep\dp\z@\dimen@
    {##1{##2\color@block{\wd\z@}{\ht\z@}{\dp\z@}\box\z@}}}%
  \colorbox%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\makeatother



\begin{document}



Of these, \pythoninline{generators} is one of the biggest culprits. I'm guessing this is the case for most novice Python programmers.

Compare: 
\colorbox{bg}{generators}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How do I control the bottom vertical length in your macro? Say I want it a bit taller at the bottom.

Comment: @blackened: Use the newer version at bottom of my answer and say `\setlength{\fboxbsep}{your value}`