# Color inline code

Tags: color, minted

I'm able to compile the following in Overleaf for the desired inline code-coloring effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.6}
\newmintinline[bluecode]{c++}{\color{codeblue}}

\begin{document}

This is a blue \bluecode{keyword} and this is a normal \mintinline[]{C++}{keyword}.
```

Which produces:

[image]

Yet I have the following errors: `Missing \endcsname inserted.` and `Package keyval Error: \color {codeblue} undefined.` I need these errors to go away so I can upload to arXiv. How can I correct this, or otherwise color inline code?

Comment: Background color is straightforward ([for example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276727/minted-package-inline-background-color)) but this is not what I'm looking for.

Comment: The last argument of `\newmintinline` isn't supposed to store arbitrary code but to pass in key=value pairs defined by the `minted` package.

Comment: Any reason why you're defining something for `c++` and then using `C++`?

Comment: @Skillmon correct. Yet this produces the desired color effect, and there is not a `color` key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following patches `\mintinline` to place the `\color` inside of it. Note that this only changes the colour of things that are not coloured by the `minted` package (you can see this in the output of `%`). The patch doesn't kill the verbatim reading of the argument.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.6}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newif\ifBlueCode
\BlueCodetrue
\newcommand*\mybluecode
  {%
    \ifBlueCode
      \global\BlueCodefalse
      \color{codeblue}%
    \fi
  }
\newrobustcmd*\bluecode[1][]
  {%
    \BlueCodetrue
    \mintinline[#1]{C++}%
  }
\expandafter\patchcmd\csname\string\mintinline\endcsname
  {\begingroup}{\begingroup\mybluecode}{}
  {\GenericError{}{Patching of \string\mintinline\space failed!}{}{}}

\begin{document}
This is a blue \bluecode{keyw%rd} and this is a normal
\mintinline[]{C++}{keyw%rd}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

To also suppress the colours placed by `minted`, you can change the definition of `\mybluecode`:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@gobble@undeclaredcolor[#1]#2{}
\newcommand*\mybluecode
  {%
    \ifBlueCode
      \global\BlueCodefalse
      \color{codeblue}%
      \let\@undeclaredcolor\@gobble@undeclaredcolor
      \let\@declaredcolor\@gobble
    \fi
  }
\makeatother
```

Comment: Works great, and thank you for the details!

Comment: However compiling seems to fail when I try to use the minted `frozencache` option: p12 of the [minted docs](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf). The error is `! Package minted Error: Missing style definition for with frozencache.` and points to the first instance of `\bluecode` in my document. Any ideas?

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain never used that option and currently I'm busy with other things. I'll take a look at it sometime later this day (if I don't forget about it, feel free to ping me with a comment if you get the feeling I've forgot you)

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain can you provide a MWE in which you have a setup that works without my patch? If I do the idiomatic thing I get errors with and without my patch.

Comment: @BoltzmannBrain Ok, just tried again, this time actually reading the manual. You have to use the `finalizecache` option and compile once before you use the `frozencache` option. It works fine with my patch applied.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution may be to write a wrapper command that first changes the color and then calls `\mintinline`. Make sure to do the color change within a group (extra `{}`) otherwise the color change can affect the text outside of the command.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{codeblue}{rgb}{0,0.3,0.6}
\newcommand{\mybluecode}[1]{%
{\color{codeblue}%
\mintinline[]{C++}{#1}}%
}
%\newmintinline[bluecode]{c++}{\color{codeblue}}

\begin{document}

This is a blue \mybluecode{keyword} and this is a normal \mintinline[]{C++}{keyword}.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This changes the effect of `\mintinline` to be almost useless. You're preventing it from changing any catcodes of `#1`.