# How can I patch `minted` to use `soul`s higlighting

Tags: minted, soul, colorbox, patching, xpatch

I'd like to highlight code with a `gray` background like StackExchange does.
I know that I can set `bgcolor` in `minted` to put a solid background color on inline code.

However, this makes `minted` use `colorbox` which doesn't wrap across long lines like markdown does:

> Here is a normal sentence that is short. `here_is_a_very_long + code_snippet + that_ends_up + wrapped`. The box does not extend into the right margin.

My understanding is that the `soul` package provides exactly this type of highlighting. My naive attempt to use it, building off the approach in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/276750/41112, was something like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{soul}

\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\setminted{breaklines=true}
\newmintinline[python]{python}{bgcolor=bg}

% this is the bit of code in question
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\minted@inputpyg@inline}{%
  \colorbox%
}{%
  \long\def\color@b@x##1##2##3%
  {\sethlcolor{##2}\hl{##3}}%
  \colorbox%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Here is a normal sentence that is short.
\python{here_is_a_very_long + code_snippet + that_ends_up + wrapped}.
The box should not extend into the right margin.
\end{document}
```

<s>Unfortunately, this appears to send LaTeX into an infinite loop; presumably because `hl` is using `colorbox` under the hood complains about a missing.</s>

Does this approach look possible? Is there a way to restore the old meaning of `\color@b@x` inside its replacement, so that this recursion is avoided?

Unfortunately, this complains about an extra `}`. Does this approach look possible? What is going wrong here?

Comment: you should show a complete example, that makes it much easier to test. But generally I would avoid soul, it is rather fragile, and try with lualatex and the lua-ul package.

Comment: @gusbrs: The `breakable` library for `tcolorbox` doesn't appear to handle breaking across lines of text, but only breaking vertically across columns. Is there another feature of `tcolorbox` I'm missing?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Updated with a full example, seems the error is different to what it was in my full document.

Comment: @Eric Yes, indeed, I had deleted the comment 'cause I saw I had misread the question. Sorry. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that it can work with soul, but with lualatex and lua-ul this seems to work (but be aware that code often can't break well over lines):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\usepackage{iftex}

\usepackage{luacolor}
\usepackage{lua-ul}

\setminted{breaklines=true}
\newmintinline[python]{python}{bgcolor=bg}

% this is the bit of code in question
\makeatletter
\newcommand\myhl[2]{\highLight[#1]{#2}}

\xpatchcmd{\minted@inputpyg@inline}{%
  \colorbox%
}{%
  \myhl%
}{\typeout{Success}}{\fail}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Here is a normal sentence that is short.
\python{here_is_a_very_long + code_snippet + that_ends_up + wrapped}.
The box should not extend into the right margin.
\end{document}
```

[image]